# How to open a User control like Keypad in wp7

Tags: windows-phone-7.1

I have a user control in my wp7 application which contains two text boxes and two buttons. I need to show it like the keypad opens. How can I do this?

Comment: do you want the control to come in a sliding manner?

Comment: @NOOB Yes, I want it to come in a sliding manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the transition effects .

```
SlideTransition sltrans = new SlideTransition();
            sltrans.Mode = SlideTransitionMode.SlideUpFadeIn;
            ITransition transition = sltrans.GetTransition(yourcontrol);
            transition.Begin();
            transition.Completed += delegate { transition.Stop(); };
```

You can set your transition effects to any user control by binding them in code behind.

I think this might suffice your requirement.